# How do I install HDMI audio driver for ASRock Core HT HTPC in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, audio

How do I install a functioning driver for the Intel HDMI Audio device in my [ASRock Core HT HTPC](http://www.asrock.com/nettop/Intel/CoreHT%20Series/) in Windows 8? The PC is based on the Intel Sandy Bridge platform with HM65/HM67 chipset. Let me know if I need to disclose more information.

Comment: Is ASRock not planning to provide updated Windows 8 drivers for this?

Comment: @Karan No idea, wish they would.